# JasperReports HTML report pagination

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pagination, jasper-reports

I'm generating an HTML report for showing table data in a web application, using **JasperReports** and **Spring MVC 3**.

Does JasperReports provide some kind of pagination method? Or, is it possible to paginate data in the generated report using some Spring MVC utilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the *JasperReports* provides some pagination methods.

***You can set this exporters parameters:***

```
JRHtmlExporterParameter.BETWEEN_PAGES_HTML
JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS
```

The ***`BETWEEN_PAGES_HTML`*** exporter parameter accepts a *java.lang.String* to replace the default page separator when exporting to *HTML* format.

When set to **Boolean.TRUE**, the ***`IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS`*** exporter
parameter ensures that all empty rows on the resulting HTML table are collapsed.

When ***`PROPERTY_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET`*** is not set, all document pages will be printed out into a single sheet. Page breaks appear as supplementary empty rows between pages.

You can read [this guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/nopagebreak/index.html) for more information and explore [this example](http://helptodeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/02/jasper-reports-with-pagination.html) for *Struts*.

***You can use the `IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION` built-in report parameter or `isIgnorePagination` report's template property.***

You can set this parameters to avoid breaking documents into multiple pages.

***You can use JasperReports API - [JasperDesign.setIgnorePagination(boolean ignorePagination)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html#setIgnorePagination%28boolean%29) method.***

---

*Additions*:

The related post on SO: [Is Jasper Reports the appropriate solution to display reports in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/640130/876298)

You can look at the sample report in *`$JASPERREPORTS_DIR$\demo\samples\nopagebreak`* folder (distributed with *JasperReports* pack).

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to put on a page very similar to the example you suggest me, with PREV and NEXT buttons.

Comment: I actually was hoping that JR was providing some integrated pagination system (something more sophisticated...)
I'll try following your indications. Thank you very much.

Comment: In new version of Jasper 6.x, no property: BETWEEN_PAGES_HTML

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at this example: http://helptodeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/02/jasper-reports-with-pagination.html and checked the `webapp` demo included in the JasperReports package (in particular the `viewer.jsp`).

I've tried to achieve something similar using Spring MVC.

In my *controller class* I've modified my *request-handling method* this way:

```
@RequestMapping("/report")
public ModelAndView showHtmlReport(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) String pageIndex,
        ModelMap model) {

    // do something...

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pageIndex)
            && StringUtils.isNumeric(pageIndex)) {
        model.put("page_index", new Integer(pageIndex));
    }

    // do something else...

    return new ModelAndView("htmlReport", model);
}
```

Then I've extended the standard `JasperReportsHtmlView` provided by Spring, overriding the `renderReport` method:

```
@Override
protected void renderReport(JasperPrint populatedReport,
        Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    // check something...

    if (model.containsKey("page_index")) {
        Map<net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter, Object> expParams = 
                this.getConvertedExporterParameters();
        expParams.put(
                net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter.PAGE_INDEX,
                model.get("page_index"));
    }

    // check something else...

    super.renderReport(populatedReport, model, response);
}
```

**NOTE:** I actually extended the html-view class for another reason ( [Images not shown in JasperReports' html report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8245832/1061499) ), but following the same approach I solved also this problem.

**NOTE pt.2:** I'm new to Spring Framework, so if my answer is not completely correct... Try to understand me! :)